# Flutter was unable to create enough overlay surfaces

Tags: flutter

Flutter was unable to create enough overlay surfaces. This is usually caused by too many platform views being displayed at once. You may experience incorrect rendering.

This is the error I am getting on flutter web. Below is the image showing the log on google chrome. Any Idea
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qugrx.png)

Above is the issue that I am facing. For more info, initially I was facing a lot of lag when the webpages was rendering and then I realised that there were so many print statements written which were logging actual data. So I removed the print statements and made the website a bit faster.
This is just to give some context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome this by using html renderer sicne it seems like some kind of bug in canvaskit.

in `index.html.web`
change the code to

```
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {

          let config = {
            renderer: "html",
          }
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine(config).then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
```